# How do it look in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello StackOver Flow friends!
Please I am a newbie
I need to convert this code to Jquery!
I am working on it but unable to make it work. I am learning javascript but I want to see how do the same code work in Jquery. What all I need. 
Now, What this function do is:

When an audio starts and as the time limit of 30 sec gets over. It Shows a confirm box whether to login for listening to the audio further or not.

If user clicks 'OK' it redirects to a login page and If the User clicks close or cancel it refreshes the page. Now What I need is that I need to make the confirm box appear with css style. So I need to change it to jquery . Or what the Masters of code think would be perfect.

```
<script>
document.addEventListener("play", function (e) {
  var audios = document.getElementsByTagName("audio");
  for (var i = 0, len = audios.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (audios[i] === e.target) {
      e.target.addEventListener("canplaythrough", function () {
        setTimeout(function () {
            e.target.pause();
            var r = confirm("Please Log in for more than 30s preview!");
            if (r == true) {
              //x = "You pressed OK!";
              window.location.href = "https://www.google.com";
            } else {
              //x = "You pressed Cancel!";
              location.reload();
            }
          },
          30000);
      }, false);

    }
  }

}, true);
</script>
```

Comment: *"I am working on it but unable to make it work."* - Which part(s) are you stuck on? Take it a bit at a time, e.g., start by replacing the use of `.getElementsByTagName()` and the loop with `$("audio").each(...)`. (Although I'm not sure that you even need a loop.) It would help if you were to [edit] your question to explain what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: what all have you you tried so far? Also paste your efforts here, this will help people to guide you better

Comment: Now, What this function do is:

When an audio starts and as the time limit of 30 sec gets over. It Shows a confirm box whether to login for listening to the audio further or not.

If user clicks 'OK' it redirects to a login page and If the User clicks close or cancel it refreshes the page. Now What I need is that I need to make the confirm box appear with css style. So I need to change it to jquery . Or what the Masters of code think would be perfect.

Comment: @Barmer Yes I am here to learn. I have coded it in Javascript but Now I only need that the confirm box should be styled not that ordinary confirm box. I am not good in designing Sir.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply @Deep . I have tried this so far that I have added a confirm box within the loop. But Now I need to style the css of Confirm box. How That Would be done?

Comment: @nnnnnn Thanks for quick reply. But What will replace getElementsByTagName() in my function?

Comment: I already said: `$("audio")`. You should do a basic jQuery tutorial or two before continuing further.

Comment: First thing is , you need not to change this javascript code to JQuery, just to use  JQuery. I believe you are trying to use Jquery dialog to make confirm box look better. Just go to this page https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation and you can learn what all files you need to add to make it working as well as the dialog implemenetation

Comment: Thanks @Deep . I follow your Instructions!

Comment: Thanks @nnnnnn . It was a great help !